# How to implement this(MyCountDownTimer) abstract class in my activity?

Tags: java, android, timer

I am a beginner so no need to downvote my question. I have an activity which increments the time in the ontick() method when pressing a certain button. If the button is clicked, the timeleft changes from:

```
Time left :5 sec
```

**to**

```
Time left :7 sec
```

How can I use this class to implement incrementation of my CountDown timer?

**Class:**

```
public abstract class MyCountDownTimer {

private CountDownTimer cdt;
private long millisInFuture;
private long countDownInterval;

public MyCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
    this.millisInFuture = millisInFuture;
    this.countDownInterval = countDownInterval;

    recreateCounter(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
}

public abstract void onFinish();

public abstract void onTick(long millisUntilFinished);

public void start(){
    cdt.start();
}

private void setMillisInFuture(long millisInFuture){
    this.millisInFuture = millisInFuture;
}

public void onIncrement(long millis){
    millisInFuture += millis;
    recreateCounter(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
}

private void recreateCounter(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval){
    if(cdt != null){
        try {
            cdt.cancel();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    cdt = new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture, countDownInterval) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            setMillisInFuture(millisUntilFinished);
            MyCountDownTimer.this.onTick(millisUntilFinished);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            MyCountDownTimer.this.onFinish();
        }
    };
  }
}
```

Help will be really appreciated!

Comment: `I am a beginner so no need to downvote my question` Great way to start. Downvotes aren't handed out because you are beginner. If you are getting downvotes it's because you did not follow site policies.

Comment: Started my Stackoverflow account yesterday. I have to get use to the policies. btw, can you help me out @Takendarkk

Comment: `How can I use this class to implement my needed methods` is way too broad of a question. Besides, what are your "needed" methods? It isn't really clear what you are asking.

Comment: incrementation of the countdown @Takendarkk